# expose public struct inside a class for boost::python

Tags: c++, python, wrapper, boost-python

I want to use this C++ class over python code with boost::python

```
/* creature.h */
class Human {
private:
public:
    struct emotion {
        /* All emotions are percentages */
        char joy;
        char trust;
        char fear;
        char surprise;
        char sadness;
        char disgust;
        char anger;
        char anticipation;
        char love;
    };
};
```

the question is how to expose this public attribute in boost-python

```
namespace py = boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    py::class_<Human>("Human");
        // I have not idea how put the public struct here
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When types are exposed through Boost.Python, they are injected into the [current scope](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/scope.html#introduction).  Some types, such as those introduced with `class_`, can be used as the current scope.

Here is a complete annotated example:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct Human
{
  struct emotion
  {
    char joy;
    // ...
  };
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)                     // set scope to example
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  {
    python::scope in_human =                     // define example.Human and set
      python::class_<Human>("Human");            // scope to example.Human

    python::class_<Human::emotion>("Emotion")    // define example.Human.Emotion
      .add_property("joy", &Human::emotion::joy) 
      ;
  }                                              // revert scope, scope is now
}                                                // example
```

Interactive Python:

```python
>>> import example
>>> e = example.Human.Emotion
>>> e
<class 'example.Emotion'>
>>> hasattr(e, 'joy')
True
```